# Is it okay to ask, if I can raise my hourly rate after only 6 months with a client as a freelancer

Tags: raise, freelancing

I'm a freelance software developer and have been working at the same rate the past 2 years. During these 2 years there have been 2 wage indexations in my country and I asked a client of mine if it was okay to raise my hourly rate with little over 3%. They are okay with this. ( I have been helping them since the beginning of my full time freelance career, 2  years ago)

Now, I have a new client since almost 6 months and I negotiated a contract for 6 months at my old hourly rate and since this contract is coming to and end I would like to ask them the same question... except, I have only been working for them during these past 6 months and I'm afraid this may come of a bit strange, since I feel they see the first 6 months an evaluation period...

Would it seem as if I'm trying to take advantage of them, asking for this raise?

PS. you could say that I'm self employed, so I decide my hourly rate, but since I'm helping this client 16-24 hours a week, they determine a large portion of my income, so I would rather ask, than just tell them about an increase.

Comment: Can always ask. VTC as opinion

Comment: This might be better suited at [freelancing.se].

Comment: Be upfront leading up to the renewal negotiation and tell them that you are expecting to up your hourly rate by 3% (whatever the actual number is) and ask them if that is going to work out for them. It is a renewal, so an increase in an hourly ask wouldn't be totally preposterous. If they like your work and you've built good relations/trust, they will most likely oblige. But expect negotiations nonetheless if you do decide to ask them for a "raise".

Comment: Agree with @DavidK that this really belong at [freelancing.se]. Presumably there they can explain to you that as a freelancer you set your own rates and how you communicate an increase to clients. I'd wager that "*Can I please have 3% more?*" is not it.

Comment: @Lilienthal sure about the Freelancing SE... but I wasn't planning on asking it that way... They should be smart enough to realise that If they don't agree with 3% I'll be looking out for another opportunity and may not agree on contract renewal.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to Freelancing SE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you pointed out, you're self employed and the existing contract is up for renewal.

**This is the best possible time to change your rate**.

It's much harder to change your rate in the middle of the contract period.

Also, since you're self employed, you probably should tell them you are increasing your rates (and why) vs. asking them.

They are not your boss, they are your customer.

Comment: this makes sense.. I'll accept your answer.. thanks for your feedback.